# multiple web app on the same tomcat instance bad or good?

Tags: java, performance, web-services, tomcat

we are going to deploy a new web services on our production servers (HP-UX).
we have already another web application deployed on our servlet container (apache-tomcat 5.5).
we have already 10 tomcat instance (for the same existing application) running smoothly on our machine behind a load balancer without any issue, the server have also enough resources to add around three new tomcat instance.

Deploying the new application on new tomcat instance could be better for administration and for application maintenance and deployment. Butwe are palnning to deploy the new application on the same 10 existent tomcat instances.

Is this a good approach?is this can be bad performance wise (memory consumption, thread pool consumption,class loading...)?

what is the best approach to proceed in this case?

Comment: not good, no problem though.

Comment: it could be bad for tomcat resource consumption as thread pool, java memory and also no that easy to maintain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have said, you have enough resources for creating new tomcat instances. you can create new one.

**Prefer simplicity over performance in the first place**. If you have resources free then what is the point of not using them.

For performance comparison could be like,

1. `If you create new tomcat instance then you need additional heap memory for new instance`. If you have that much memory available then go for new instance. After initial monitoring you can tune/resize the heap memory for performance.
2. `Using existing instance, will allow you to run application in existing memory. But thread pool and memory will be shared with other applications` deployed on same instance. You may not get optimal performance of either application or in worst case for both applications.
3. `For memory operation on single instance, You will have to create new configuration` for swapping, caching priorities of application. Which application should have low priority at the time of peak utilization. Even at the end of load balancing also additional configs are required.
4. On the other hand, new instance will allow to run dedicated application with dedicated thread pool at the cost of additional memory and additional cpu requests. `If you have enough resources then seperate instance is a good choice for mgmt and performance perspective`.

I hope you are clear now :)